# com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient and NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, asynchttpclient

I'm using `com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient` to open a web socket connection as follows.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
try {
    client.prepareGet(url)
         .execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder()
                 .addWebSocketListener(new WebSocketListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "opened");
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "closed");
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "error");
                     }
                 }).build());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is outlined in the github documentation https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client.

However I'm seeing `onError` being called each time with a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception.

Why is this? Do I really need a separate thread in which the client can operate or an instance of AsyncTask?

Comment: use `AsyncTask` class

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't think it is a duplicate. I expected that AsyncHttpClient would already work asynchronously and call back to the main thread. i.e. it would not block.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the documentation,

> Async Http Client library purpose is to allow Java applications to
>   easily execute HTTP requests and asynchronously process the HTTP
>   responses.

suggests that the request execution blocks but the response handling does not.